# jScrollPane dont work if set font for <body>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sashaua/89ABc/) all works

But if you [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivbtnpvkyqa0qdn/scroll.zip) and run index.html on your PC - scroller doesn't work.

If delete font: `12px/16px Arial;` in css/style.css :

```
body {
    font: 12px/16px Arial;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
}
```

it works, if set dimension in `em` all is well, but if dimension set in `pixel`, scroller doesn't work.

Comment: did you check the console of your application?, Tried to see if you have errors in the Browser

Comment: In chrome no errors, all the libraries are connected.